# Using Greatest Common Divisor for a ratio in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, greatest-common-divisor

I would like to write a method in Objective-C that will result in a text string 'a:b:c:d'.  I have four UISteppers (their values are displayed in a label each).  I would like the ratio of those four numbers to display in their lowest integer form, including if some are 0.

Eg. a=6, b=4, c=0, d=0
Textstring = 3:2:0:0

I have found various ways of finding the greatest common divisor including http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=35759.  However, I'm really new to iOS, this is my first app after Hello World, and the maths functions and even declaring a method, defining it and calling it are still a mystery.

Can you help out?

Comment: If you don't know how to declare, define, and call a method, you need to work through some tutorials before tackling this problem.

Comment: I'm working through them at the same time!

Comment: Right, sorted it. It took a little while to sort out which data types each variable should be, but I now have methods almost sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I settled for a method that takes the label values and alters the ratio label:

```
- (void)CalculateRatio {
   int temp;
   int PRBCs = [self.labelPRBCs.text integerValue];
   int FFP = [self.labelFFP.text integerValue];
   int u = PRBCs;
   int v = FFP;
   while (v != 0) {
       temp = u % v;
       u = v;
       v = temp;
   }
   int PRBCratio = PRBCs / u;
   int FFPratio = FFP / u;
   double Plateletratio = [self.labelPlatelets.text doubleValue] / u;
   double Cryoratio = [self.labelCryo.text doubleValue] / u;
   NSString *returnValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d : %.1lf : %.1lf", PRBCratio, FFPratio, Plateletratio, Cryoratio];
   self.calculatedRatio.text = returnValue;
}
```

If you can see some syntactical errors, ways to improve this, I'd be happy to hear them.
Cheers.